# Why is Wildfly 17 complaining about missing BearerTokenAuthenticationMechanism ctor?

Tags: security, wildfly, wildfly-17

we're trying to upgrade from Wildfly 15 to Wildfly 17. When starting the application under 17 we get lot's of DEBUGs in log as follows:

```
2019-07-16 08:30:41,031|DEBUG|          org.jboss.as.domain.management|Identification of operation not progressing after [15000000000] ns has been requested
2019-07-16 08:30:51,029|DEBUG|                     io.undertow.request|Matched prefix path /management for path /management
2019-07-16 08:30:51,029|DEBUG|            io.undertow.request.security|Setting authentication required for exchange HttpServerExchange{ POST /management}
2019-07-16 08:30:51,029|DEBUG|                    org.wildfly.security|Unable to create instance
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: ELY00011: Unable to create service for 'HttpServerAuthenticationMechanismFactory.BEARER_TOKEN' 
    at org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronProvider$ProviderService.newInstance(WildFlyElytronProvider.java:342)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.util.SecurityProviderServerMechanismFactory.getMechanismNames(SecurityProviderServerMechanismFactory.java:79)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.util.SetMechanismInformationMechanismFactory.getMechanismNames(SetMechanismInformationMechanismFactory.java:58)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.util.FilterServerMechanismFactory.getMechanismNames(FilterServerMechanismFactory.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.util.SortedServerMechanismFactory.getMechanismNames(SortedServerMechanismFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.HttpAuthenticationFactory.getAllSupportedMechNames(HttpAuthenticationFactory.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.AbstractMechanismAuthenticationFactory.getMechanismNames(AbstractMechanismAuthenticationFactory.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.lambda$secureDomainAccess$3(ManagementHttpServer.java:447)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:253)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.access$800(HttpAuthenticator.java:242)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:96)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.wildfly.security.http.bearer.BearerTokenAuthenticationMechanism.<init>(java.security.Provider)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronProvider$ProviderService.newInstance(WildFlyElytronProvider.java:339)
```

Why is this and how can I get rid of these log entries?

Best regards
Mark.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the WildFlyElytronProvider, I have created the following so we can implement a fix - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ELY-1847

As this is just a DEBUG message you should be able to ignore in the meantime if you are not trying to use this mechanism.